# Where can I find the source image files for the browser checkboxes in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, graphics

I'm looking for the source PNG image files for the browser checkboxes used in Safari.

Specifically, these guys:

[image]

I've looked through the `Contents > Resources` folder in the Safari.app file, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [ArtTools](http://www.mediafire.com/?n6m93tsgmmd). It helps you decode the UI elements file.
2. Go here: `System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUIFramework/Versions/A/Resources`.
3. Copy the *.bin files to a folder on your desktop.
4. Copy the *.jar files of ArtTools to the same folder.
5. Run the following command: `java -jar artDecoder.jar SArtFile.bin SArtFile.bin/`.
6. Do this for all the *.bin files.
7. Browse through the extracted files and you will find the checkbox there.